# Need to add the output of a function to the array it works on

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm trying to write a powershell script that extracts some data from NetBackup.  One of the data points is the start date of the backup, but NetBackup outputs that in a Unix format (number of seconds since 01/01/1970 I believe).

I have the extract section working.  I can convert the date string in to a usable format using a function I found online.  What I'm struggling with is putting the corrected date back in to the original array.

So $BackupResults is the extract from NetBackup:

Sample

jobid                                                    started                                                  status
-----                                                    -------                                                  ------
330447                                                   1562743826                                               0
330446                                                   1562743557                                               191
330445                                                   1562743556                                               191

I've then declared the conversion function and run a foreach loop on the results putting the results in $CorrectedDates.  What I can't work out is how to add that back in to the original array - either by combining the arrays or just by writing the output straight in to the $BackupResults array.

```
$CorrectedDates = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$BackupResults = Get-NetBackupJob -Full | Select-Object jobid,started,status

Function Convert-FromUnixDate ($UnixDate) {
   [timezone]::CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(([datetime]'1/1/1970').AddSeconds($UnixDate))
}


Foreach ($BackupResult in $BackupResults)
{
$OutDate = Convert-FromUnixDate $BackupResult.started
[void]$CorrectedDates.add($OutDate)
}

$BackupResults = New-Object psobject
$BackupResults | add-member -name Date -type noteproperty -Value $CorrectedDates
```

The version above works without errors but $BackupResults ends up as a row of the corrected dates, rather than the corrected dates appended to each row in the original data:

```
{10/07/2019 08:45:57, 10/07/2019 08:45:57, 10/07/2019 08:45:57, 10/07/2019 08:30:26...}
```

What I'd like is the original $BackupResults out but with an extra column with each unix date converted into a human date (don't care what the output array is called).  This will then be used to setup some monitoring.

EDIT:

Not sure I'm allowed to re-open a query, but starting over would be difficult as I would like to expand on the original question.

I'm now trying to filter the results before I output.  Specifically, I only want results where the date stamp is within the last 24 hours and the status code returned is 2.  I'm guessing I need to use .AddDays(-1) somewhere on line 18 l, but I can't find a place where the that's valid?  And how do I filter the Status line output?

Comment: Could you not use append the converted time to the current value in your foreach loop? So using:
$outDate = Convert-FromUnixDate $BackupResults.Started
$BackupResult.started = $BackupResult + " : " + $outDate
Never done something like this before, thought I leave a comment with a suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in one go, using a calculated expression:

```
function ConvertFrom-UnixTimeStamp([Int64]$unixTimeStamp, [switch]$asUtc) {
    if ($unixTimeStamp -gt 253402430399) {
        Write-Error "Cannot convert $unixTimeStamp to DateTime. Only integer values up to 253402430399 are valid."
    }
    elseif ($unixTimeStamp -gt [Int32]::MaxValue) {
        Write-Warning "The given value exceeds the [Int32]::MaxValue and therefore enters the Year2038 Unix bug.."
    }
    # a Unix timestamp is in UTC
    [DateTime]$origin = New-Object System.DateTime 1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, Utc

    if ($asUtc) { return $origin.AddSeconds($unixTimeStamp) }
    return ($origin.AddSeconds($unixTimeStamp)).ToLocalTime()
}


$BackupResults = Get-NetBackupJob -Full | 
                    Select-Object jobid,
                                  @{Name = 'started'; Expression = {ConvertFrom-UnixTimeStamp $_.started}},
                                  status
```

I have changed your code to translate the unix timestamp into a datetime object, so given timestamp is treated as UTC as it should.

Result:

> ```
>  jobid started            status
>  ----- -------            ------
> 330447 10-7-2019 09:30:26      0
> 330446 10-7-2019 09:25:57    191
> 330445 10-7-2019 09:25:56    191
> ```

<sup>Note, I am running this on a Dutch machine, so the dateformat in your case could be different.</sup>

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you so much for this - I've got a lot to learn about powershell - your solution does exactly what I need.